# Captcha Refresh (Future Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, submit, captcha

I've followed few tuts here and there and made my own captcha with session that I want to implement into my bigger project. The captcha should be used like everywhere else, in the contact / send email section to prevent spam repetition.

Problem - if you miss the captcha and hit back button, the captcha doesn't refresh. This is as good as its bad, and with ajax it means the captcha won't refresh the page and the captcha won't refresh on its own. Since the captcha is made in a different file, I guess calling the same file again should fix the problem.

Solution - I would want a 3 try system, if the captcha isn't guessed 3 times then the page is refreshed.

PHP CAPTCHA code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$text = rand(10000, 99999);
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $text;
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 25, 25, 25);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);


$font = 'Candara.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

HTML TEST CODE:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Message: <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
Captcha: <input type="text" name="val_code"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="generate captcha.php"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

SUBMIT PHP CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST["val_code"] != $_SESSION['captcha'] OR $_SESSION['captcha'] == '') {
echo "<b><font style='color: purple'>Wrong captcha value. Please go back and resend the message</font></b>";
}
else
{
echo "<b><font style='color: green'>Thank you for your message!</font></b>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a counter that will keep track of the number of tries. Also, make sure to unset the captcha so that it can't be reused. See the codes below:

PHP CAPTCHA code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['tries'] < 2 && $_SESSION['captcha']) {
    $text = $_SESSION['captcha'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['tries'] = 0;
    $text = rand(10000, 99999);
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $text;
}
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 25, 25, 25);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);


$font = 'Candara.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['tries']>=2) {
   echo "<b><font style='color: purple'>Captcha has expired! You need to go back and reload the page</font></b>";
} else if($_POST["val_code"] != $_SESSION['captcha'] OR $_SESSION['captcha'] == '') {
echo "<b><font style='color: purple'>Wrong captcha value. Please go back and resend the message</font></b>";
$_SESSION['tries']++;
}
else
{
unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
unset($_SESSION['tries']);
echo "<b><font style='color: green'>Thank you for your message!</font></b>";
}
?>
```

html test code:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Message: <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
Captcha: <input type="text" name="val_code"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="generate captcha.php" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: There is something wrong in the code at the captcha php. It only works if the $text var is before the if. It doesn't work if the variable is inside the if.

Comment: The code gets stuck - the first time it works great. But after the 'page refresh' the session vars aren't being unset and the if clause generates an empty image since $text var isn't existent in the first if. The code needs more correction

Comment: it should be `$text = $_SESSION['captcha'];` <-- i updated the code

Comment: The new image doesn't get refreshed and the session captcha and tries are getting stuck I believe.

Comment: yes, the user can go back and try two more times if s/he fails

Comment: With your current code right now - even page reload doesn't end the session. You aren't resetting the session variables if the guest misses the captcha, and the page refresh doesn't make a new picture. The code gets stuck

Comment: does changing `if ($_SESSION['tries'] >= 2) {` to `if ($_SESSION['tries'] <= 2) {` solve the problem?

Comment: nope. The image is stuck, page reload doesn't do anything at all and even if submit button is clicked with correct captcha, the expired captcha message appears.

Comment: i'm sorry - i had this tested now in my localhost. i found the error. hopefully, this is the last edit i'm making. :)

Comment: third line in captcha generation

Comment: Sweet, works flawlessly this time. It took 3-4 changes, but now its great :)